# firefox browser closes as soon as excecution of script is completed in selenium excel

Tags: excel, selenium

I am trying to scrape web elements using selenium wrapper excel VBA. Firefox browser closes as soon as the execution of code is completed. Is there any way to keep the bowser open ?

Comment: comment the line which closes the browser. like browser.Close

Comment: This question has been answered previously here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857246/selenium-vba-exit-sub-without-close-browser-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857246/selenium-vba-exit-sub-without-close-browser-window)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The browser should be in Open state !!!